# How to run an xcode project from bash?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a build script calling xcodebuild. that works, but I want to also run the project from bash as well. Effectively I want  to negate the need to click "Build and Run" button from the GUI. I'm looking at xcrun but it's not too obvious to me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run the *product* of the build, not the project itself. If you want to do that, you just need to use the bash invocation for the product. If you're building a command-line program, then there will be an executable with the product's name in the project's built products directory after a succesful build. The project's built products directory depends on your preferences for Xcode and the project, but can be determined from the `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` environment variable within an Xcode build phase.

Answer (score 2):

I do this for one of my projects in a shell script. It let's me remotely build over SSH.

```
xcodebuild clean
xcodebuild
cp -rp ~/Projects/VSM/Mac/iCar/build/Release/iCar.app ~/Desktop/
open ~/Desktop/iCar.app
```

I chose to copy the app to the Desktop on purpose but you wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

try `open xcode`

Comment: Trying to find where that executable actually is

Comment: You should have a directory named `Developer` (or something like that)  at the root of your hard disk